# How to plot sea routes in google maps?

Tags: google-maps

How do websites like https://www.marinetraffic.com/en/voyage-planner, http://www.searoutefinder.com/ plot sea routes in google maps ?

Answer (score 2):

The Google Maps APIs do not currently support ocean or air travel at this time. That being said, it looks like the sites you mentioned are using polylines to get the route. There is a good article on polylines here:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/polyline-simple

That article has a JSFiddle which shows how one could use polylines for a flight plan. A sea route would follow the same logic. You create the path for the route using lat,lng coordinates like so:

```
var searRouteCoordinates = [
{lat: 37.772, lng: -122.214},
{lat: 21.291, lng: -157.821},
{lat: -18.142, lng: 178.431},
{lat: -27.467, lng: 153.027}
];
```

You can think of each lat,lng pair as a waypoint along the route. Currently this is the only way to show a sea or air route.

I hope this helps!